# Maps API zoom into an overlay

Tags: javascript, html, api, maps, overlays

Here is what I have done so far(had to wrap in a anchor tag for some reason...)

```
<a src="http://jsfiddle.net/christian4423/6oe9gLLn/"></a>
```

With each area being a region I want to zoom into when clicked. How would I do so?
As far as my research shows there is no more click event with V3.
If I am wrong please let me know, and how could I make it zoom to the overlay within its bounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A shape should respond to a click event and it responds

```
// In your case
google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, 'click', function() {
    // Zoom as you wish here
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 2); 
});
```

Perharps you should also set the center of map to the center of polygone.

Br

Comment: Ha that was easy! I was overthinking it lol. Thank you very much kind sir!